# Test async function in React with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have component, where i apply styles to the component with async function, and i need to cover this function with Enzyme test.

```
const SpinnerKf = new Keyframes.Spring({
  loading: async (next: Object) => {
    await next(getCircleStyles(0.5, '#fff'))
    await next(getCircleStyles(34, styles.colorSuccess))
  }
})

export class Spinner {
   ...

   render () {
     <SpinnerKf>...</SpinnerKf>   
   }
}
```

How can I check with Enzyme, that function in the second `await` return correct color (second argument in `getCircleStyles`)? When i check color on `SpinnerKf`, it's return only `#fff` (color from the first await), but I need to check second await too.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could `jest.mock` the `Keyframes`. I'm not sure where you import it from, but if you mock everything down to the loading function and pass in a spy `next` function, you can assert the colors pass to `next`.

Animations are tricky to test, and thorough testing would involve a lot of mocking. It could not be for it.